# How to match single digit in a string using regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string:

```
AB_INV_23_some_value
```

I want to check the number after `AB_INV_`. Condition is that the number should not be more than 4 (and it should be a single digit number).

I wrote a pattern:

```
^(AB)_(INV)_[0-4]{1}
```

However, this pattern is a matches `AB_INV_23_some_value`, while it shouldn't, because `23` is 2-digit number that is more than 4. Please assist.

Comment: Would `[^0-9][0-4][^0-9]` work?

Comment: Try [`^AB_INV_[0-4](?!\d)`](https://regex101.com/r/6X7n2E/1)

Comment: HI Wiktor, it works. Thanks a ton. Will you be able to explain that expression given by you?

Comment: @Aniruddha See my answer with an explanation below.

Comment: Hi ClasG, Thanks for your input, but the pattern given by you is caught in expception :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your pattern, `[0-4]{1}` matches exactly 1 digit from `0` to `4`, but it does not check what comes after that digit. There may be anything, even the end of string, or another digit.

You may use

```
^AB_INV_[0-4](?!\d)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6X7n2E/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `AB_INV_` - a literal substring
- `[0-4]` - a digit from `0` ot `4`...
- `(?!\d)` - that is not followed by any other digit.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with the regex

```
AB_INV_(?![5-9]_)\d{1,4}_
```

see the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1XAYy1/3)